# What is the policy towards people "carpet bombing" StackOverflow with newbie questions?

Tags: discussion

Once in a while the behavior of a StackOverflow user drives me crazy and I don't know whether my behavior is wrong or the behavior of that user is wrong.

Allow me to give an example. Today I was confronted with the following questions:

- [Draw a borderless table in iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006547/draw-a-borderless-table-in-itextsharp)
- [What is the PdfPTable.DefaultCell property used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006618/what-is-the-pdfptable-defaultcell-property-used-for)
- [PdfContentByte.SetColorFill vs. PdfContentByte.SetRGBColorFill and how to write strikethrough text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006686/pdfcontentbyte-setcolorfill-vs-pdfcontentbyte-setrgbcolorfill-and-how-to-write)
- [Color the background of a piece of text in a PDF document using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006767/color-the-background-of-a-piece-of-text-in-a-pdf-document-using-itextsharp)
- [Draw a rectangle at the *current position* and then get its position coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006925/draw-a-rectangle-at-the-current-position-and-then-get-its-position-coordinates)
- [Why doesn't FontFactory.GetFont("Known Font Name", floatSize) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007492/why-doesnt-fontfactory-getfontknown-font-name-floatsize-work)

All of these questions were posted by *the same user* within a time-span of 2 hours.

There are some time-limits on StackOverflow (e.g. you only get 5 minutes to edit a comment), but there doesn't seem to be a limitation of the number of questions one can ask per day.

This isn't necessarily a problem, but in the case of these questions, I have my doubts.

The answer to the first question is trivial: if you don't want a cell to have a border, use `cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);` This is documented on many places. It's the most basic question one can ask about a table.

I wouldn't have made a problem about this question if the same person wouldn't have posted follow-up questions. On its own, the second question about the *default cell* is OK. There's no reason to down-vote or to close it. However, it overlaps with the first question. The two questions could easily have been combined.

The third question is strange: the OP confuses 'stroke' with 'strike' and this results in a somewhat absurd question mixing low-level PDF syntax with the concept of striking a line through text.

The fourth question was answered by the OP himself, but the answer was incorrect. The fifth question is a duplicate of that question, but it can't be marked as a duplicate because question 4 doesn't have an accepted answer yet.

Question six is a good question, but by now, you get the idea what I mean by carpet-bombing StackOverflow: all of these questions can be answered by pointing at resources that are available on the official site of the product the OP is using, yet the OP thought it wise to fire 6 questions in 2 hours time...

Who is wrong in this case? Am I wrong thinking that this behavior isn't appropriate on StackOverflow, or is the OP wrong when he comments (I quote): *I beg to differ with your extremely arrogant opinion.*

In another comment, the OP claims that one can't expect a developer to find his way through a large portion of documentation. It seems as he's using SO to learn how to use a tool by posting one question after the other. I've always seen SO as a place to get answers to a specific programming problem. I've never seen it as a place where you go to learn how to use a tool. Maybe I'm wrong, but 6 questions by the same person in less than 2 hours time feels like too much...

Comment: Newbies can only drop one bomb every 90 minutes. That's the policy; low-rep users are rate limited to minimize carpet bombing.

Comment: You're too conscious about your reputation. Like everything, reputation must be managed as well and cannot just be made a "fact". Your rep may come from a Broad knowledge or a Narrow knowledge - Please tell me which is worth more?

Comment: OK, I'll remove the remark about my reputation. The question remains: is SO an alternative for learning how to use a tool?

Comment: Just to complete the information on the involved limits, the user hit the 6 questions per day limit, and there is also a 50 questions per month limit.

Comment: And the full reference for rate limiting is: [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just concentrate on:

> Is SO an alternative for learning how to use a tool?

SO is a Q&A site for programmers. Some post far more Qs than As and others the other way around. Is there a limit to the ratio of Q/A where it feels like the exchange is only one way? I don't know.

**But each question should be well researched, useful and clearly written.**

If this is not the case feel free to downvote. If the questions are duplicates feel free to flag them.

In the end SO can be used for learning how to use a tool as long as the questions are well researched, useful and clearly written.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly read the question [Draw a borderless table in iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006547/draw-a-borderless-table-in-itextsharp) here again before you accuse others of not having done their homework.

I find your kind who think they are the only ones who invest time reading stuff and the others are taking it easy extremely peevish and self-conceited.

I spent over 20 hours before organizing notes and my questions and posting them on Stack Overflow.

The question I asked said, "I already know that you could set a border for a cell. Is there a way to set it for the whole table in one go?"

Please do not mislead others or yourself. You seem to have been answering my questions rather tangentially. In all your answers, I sense a bit of bitterness, not to mention, some of them are tangential and do not address the issue I am raising.

As to other people reading this, I would like to point out that this person (I am aware of who he is) is objecting to my questions posted today about iTextSharp.

Look, for instance, at his comments on this question.

[Why doesn't FontFactory.GetFont("Known Font Name", floatSize) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24007492/303685)

My question is not a 101 about "hey, how do I do this?" It's in a manner of curiosity about "why are things this way. They didn't work when I did that but worked when I did the other. Why so?"

I would like to point out that all of you being developers should appreciate that we all developers work very hard sacrificing our personal time to learn so many things. We are already finding it so hard coping with life with the pace at which new tools are being thrown at us.

Is it not pure vanity then for someone to come and say, "Oh, look. You haven't done your homework. First read those 1,500 pages of cryptic, half-baked documentation, buy my book and then come and ask."

How many tools do you have to use to get your job done daily?

I find I have to use a new thing every day, sometimes two new tools to learn every day at my job.

How can one even keep up? And I am a very diligent developer. Just because I don't know as much as this guy because he happened to have authored the tool and the book, I find it extremely arrogant of him to point a finger on someone who *actually* *has* done quite a bit of work.

I find it very humiliating and extremely out of place for a person like that to say something like he did.

Comment: Er... what's wrong with the answer to the "Draw a borderless table in iTextSharp"? Borders are defined at the cell level, not the table level, therefore the answer is correct: you make sure that no cell has a border. For custom requirements, one uses cell and table events. I wouldn't know of any other way to answer this. I don't see any bitterness in the answer. It is what it is. It's an emotionless answer, but that's what happens when you explain a technical issue.

Comment: I am not saying there's anything wrong with the answer. I am saying, on this post, you're implying that that is a simple question and I should have known *how to set a border on a cell and that that was what I was asking*, which happens to be wrong. Anyway. Honestly, I would rather spend my time writing some code rather than defending myself to someone who I don't expect to understand. Please be happy with control over the fact that you can label others are lesser than you in one way or another, if it makes you happy.

Comment: My answer to the `FontFactory` question was concise and to the point. You are trying to use a font that isn't registered and you get an 'undefined/unknown' font. Once you register the font, you get the font you need. In my answer, I explain why registering is necessary: if we'd register all fonts on your system by the start, you'd waste time and memory.

Comment: I would much rather spend my very limited time building something for my customer. Nevertheless, thank you for your answers. I did find them useful and I am not debating that at all.

Comment: That's a whole other discussion: are you a paying iText user? Does your customer have a valid iText license for your use of iText on his systems?

Comment: Not yet, but I am trying it out and please be assured that if I do, we will pay you.

Comment: @CodyGray: Because he made a very personal attack at me on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/24007492/303685 saying, "Reading your questions, you seem to be in the category of the people who didn't do any effort to learn..." with some preaching.

Comment: If that's the problem, I have no problem removing that comment. The comment was finished with the expression "Just my 2 cents." Meaning that what I wrote wasn't necessarily a valuable opinion. I wrote this Meta question to explain the more fundamental problem. You are claiming that technical answers sound bitter. That's a strange approach. You are claiming that my answers are tangential, but you're not explaining why they aren't helpful.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2, calling out an abusive higher up takes guts and good on you for doing it!

Comment: @GayotFow: Thanks. Even another question of mine here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006618/what-is-the-pdfptable-defaultcell-property-used-for shows that I read the documentation. The product is very poorly documented. And now, seeing his attitude, I am very discouraged from going further with it.

Comment: Gayot I'd hardly call a user that answered each of his questions in detail abusive..... and @WaterCoolerv2 I hope it wasn't you down voting his answers....

Comment: @OGHaza: He answered my questions and I was grateful for that until I saw his preachy comment, which he has now deleted. The comment accused me of being lazy and not having done my homework, while completely overlooking the fact that the product is sparsely documented.

Comment: @OGHaza: I sure hope my questions are very valid. I know they are. Someone was downvoting them, too. I am not asking anyone who it was?

Comment: I gave a 'my 2 cents' comment. It's amazing why you make such a fuss about it. I didn't down-vote your questions. Each separate question is a normal question. I would have voted to close the background chunk question but I couldn't because that requires an accepted or up-voted answer. I down-voted your answer to one question, because it risks confusing people with the same problem. In my opinion, you're biting the hand that tries to help you. I'm sorry, but that's really strange.

Comment: "because someone downvoted my question" is not a great reason for blindly downvoting answers... if wasn't you then great

Comment: I haven't downvoted your questions either except for one. So, please do not assume it was me, just because I asked that I not be asked.

Comment: I assume you are referring to an answer, not to a question. In any case: saying "The product is very poorly documented" to an author who was allowed to write a second edition of his book published by Manning Publication is uncalled for. The Manning team that worked on the book consisted of 15 people, not including professional reviewers. If you think the product is poorly documented: you can always help others by writing better documentation. Your attitude is destructive and demotivates the many people who write documentation for free. Don't be the pot that calls the kettle black.

Comment: Your product is poorly documented. That's a fact. Having a book on sale does not mean that your product is well-documented. I am surprised that you're saying that I am the one creating the fuss when you were the person who started this thread. Most of your answers mention your book. When I am evaluating a product, I'd like to learn as much as I can online and then buy a book afterwards if it appeals to me.

Comment: With that, I'd like to state that your comments just drove a potential customer away. I spent from 1 AM this morning up to 11 AM reading various articles and blogs and documentation and trying things out on iTextSharp. I spent an equal amount of time yesterday. But I have to admit. I am so not spending another second. I really loved the product and was almost bought into it. It's a great product. But I am left with a bad after-taste now. So, I'm going to be looking for something else. You will not have to tolerate another question from me about iTextSharp.

Comment: Let me know if you find a tool with better documentation that is as feature-rich as iTextSharp. Also don't forget to fill out our survey: https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/iText-community (It has a list of competing products.)

Comment: I already had it in mind (if I couldn't use iTextSharp, as Plan B when I set out) to use use either OpenXML or COM Interop/OLE Automation to write to a Word document and then use the Office PDF Tools to programmatically convert that Word document to a PDF. Works great, has great documentation. Too bad, I had almost come to loving iTextSharp. But sorry, I am not going to spend any more time on anything, not even a survey. You're a great developer, I am sure of that. I am also sure that others will find it useful.